# Prim's algorithm "values stored in array"

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

InPrim’s algorithm, if we do not use the min-priority queue and store all the key values in an array, what will be the running time of the modified algorithm?

Comment: How will the array be used?

Comment: It would be `O(E.V)` since each operation of finding/updating the min-edge-wt in the array would be in worse case the number of vertices.